# Filtered ID in Regex rule for IIS URL rewrite

Tags: regex, iis, rules

In IIS I need to rewrite some URLs of the following format ...

`https://intranet.test.ch/default.asp?rq_AppGuid=1797F2EBEDBAA87403CF202FD726B63FBB064C02&rq_TargetPageGuid=3851012A27819643BB79B647961B0D668FB9FD08&rq_RecId=31333535&rq_Lang=de`

to
`https://intranet.test.ch/doc/1355`

From the first URL the ID is URL encoded 31333535 = 1355

So actually I need to extract the ID and used it to redirect to the other URL.

With `(?<=&rq_RecId=)\d*` I can geht the ID, but without filtering the not needed 3s. Also the ID can be between 1-9999, means 31-39393939.

Can this be done with regex, so I have a resulting group to use in the redirecting URL?

Comment: You cannot capture/match disjoint pieces of text within one match operation. No regex allows that.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean, but if you want to encode in iis url rewrite, you can consider `{UrlEncode:{}}`.